# How often do mower blades need to be sharpened?

Tags: lawn, lawn-mower, mowing

An important practice in toxin-free (and other) turf care is to only mow with sharp blades. So how often do I have to sharpen the blades?

I'm sure that it will depend on conditions, but is there some general guideline? Is it based on area mowed? Hours mowed? After so many months?

And are there industry standards that professionals follow?

Answer (score 5):

Depends on the mower you're using - if its just an ordinary electric hover mower with a rotary blade, or a non hover with a rotor blade, you just buy a new blade when its blunt or damaged, unless you want to put it in for a service every year, when they might do it if it needs it. If you can find someone to sharpen it, or you can do it yourself, fine, but in the UK, unless you sharpen it yourself, you won't find anyone to do it - replacement rotary blades for a flymo, for instance, are around a tenner, or £10, so not expensive, and I've only had to buy 2 blades in 30 years, mostly because they were either bent or badly chipped.

If you've got a cylinder mower, specially if its got an engine rather than being electric, its usual to have those serviced yearly by a lawn mower servicing company. The service may, or may not, include sharpening blades, that's something you'd have to ask them about. Most professional gardeners with large petrol mowers are quite capable of keeping their mowers functioning well, but not always including sharpening - if the mower is heavily used, it will be put it in for a full service yearly as a minimum. Groundkeepers are probably even more rigorous and are often capable of stripping down and replacing parts on their mowers, as well as sharpening.

As for how you know when the blades need sharpening, its impossible to predict - there's a big difference between a mower being used every day for 4 or 7 hours, and one that's only used once or twice a week. Damage may occur to the blades from stones or other objects hidden within the grass, and may cause the blades to be warped, chipped or simply blunt in parts.

If you're cutting grass all day long with a petrol cylinder mower, it'll likely need sharpening in spring and probably mid season. Otherwise, the easiest way to tell is by looking at the grass after you've finished - if the cut is uneven, then the blades need attention. If you're using a cylinder mower of any sort, inspect the top part of the cut grass - if it looks cleanly cut, then the blades are sharp, but if the ends look a bit chewed or tatty, then the blades need attention. This doesn't apply with rotary blades - they don't make a clean cut in the same way.

Comment: Buy a new one every year? When you can sharpen them in less than ten minutes? Wow, that's not normal around here...

Comment: @J. Musser That's not what I've said - I said buy a new ROTARY blade 'when its blunt or damaged' not every year  - I've only ever bought two replacement blades in 30 years, so I think you've misunderstood. Blades are only about a tenner - easier to replace because its impossible to find anyone who'll sharpen them here in the UK if you can't do it yourself. So I think you're not really grasping what I'm saying...

Comment: @J.Musser - if you've misunderstood, then others might, so I've edited my answer to cover for that.

Comment: All good, Bamboo! As you've said before, lawns in the US are usually bigger than those in the UK. I have about 2 acres of lawn here at my spread, and I usually have to sharpen every couple months. Also partly due to running over all the sticks and stuff that fall from the trees. Not that it matters...

Answer (score 5):

It depends on a lot of factors but for rotary mowers, every 20 to 25 hours is a good interval to sharpen your blades. For some people that means once a year, for others twice a year. For commercial landscapers it's once or more a week.

You can also just look at the blades of grass the next day or so after mowing. If the tips have a large (1/4" or so) ragged and brown looking area instead of just a small line of brown then it's past the time to sharpen your blades. Dull blades leave cuts that don't heal as quickly, are easier to be affected by disease and require more water than lawns mowed with a sharp blade.

I keep 2 blades for my mower so I can swap them out and sharpen at my convenience. When I started sharpening my mower blades twice a year it seemed to make a big difference. The sharpening before summer seems like a good idea. Learning how to sharpen your mower blade isn't hard nor is it time consuming. There are tools available that can make it easier and faster too. Though mower blades aren't that expensive I find it more convenient to sharpen than to purchase a new one.

I have some more info on my site in the articles [Time to Change Your Mower Blade](http://www.organiclawndiy.com/2014/06/time-to-change-your-mower-blade.html) and [Mowing Tips for a Healthy Lawn](http://www.organiclawndiy.com/2009/06/mowing-tips-for-healthy-lawn.html) if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

Great answer, Bamboo.  The old but best-to-cut-grass-with reel mower is easy to keep the blades sharp with a file or stone.  Rotary blades need to be removed to sharpen correctly.  At the very least make SURE THE SPARK PLUG IS DISENGAGED before messing with that blade!!!  Rotary blades DO need to be sharpened regularly and I've gone and purchased extra blades for all rotary mowers.  I take 2 or 3 in to the lawn equipment service store to have them professionally sharpened so all I have to do is change out the blade once per month or as soon as you see the grass tips getting ratty.  This rattiness causes a 'dusty' look to ones lawn and could cause vulnerability to disease.  If you know how to sharpen knives, pruners, hedge shears then great.  DIY.  Otherwise, they are not that expensive to keep extras professionally sharpened so change your blades out as often as you want! Don't forget to wipe with alcohol especially if you are doing maintenance on more than just your lawn! KEEP YOUR GRASS NO SHORTER THAN 3"!!! (if you have blue grass/fescue type lawn) Mow every day if you want but no less than once per week!

Comment: It was my understanding that reel mowers are really only useful for cutting/maintaining turf at shorter lengths. This would make them less appropriate for toxin-free turf management, which calls for cutting turf to 3" or more.

Comment: I have a reel mower and never use any "product" on my lawn. The two are by no means incompatible. I have an acre and a half and the reel mower is not motorized.

Comment: The reel mower is the best, especially if it isn't motorized.  Not only do you save by not hiring gardeners, you save by not needing a therapist or even a personal trainer or gym!  I've used them of course but not much.  If you are unable to raise your reel mower so that you are able to brush the tips and leave a minimum of 3"...I'd get another that CAN be adjustable.  Golf course lawns are not what you want for residential!  A lot of golf courses use Poa annua, a short rooted, light green native grass that you DON'T want in your homes' lawns!

Comment: Kate!  What a perfect workout!  But are you telling me that you DON'T fertilize?  At any rate you should try Dr. Earth's Lawn Fertilizer!! It is worth every penny!!  It is very 'organic' and more importantly 'extended release'...This is the only lawn fertilizer that made enuf of an impression on me so that I actually remember its name!!  And I am very familiar with lawn maintenance!!  Are you able to maintain 3"???

Comment: I am unable to remain quiet about the use of the word 'toxin'. Too broad of a label.  Us humans are bags of chemicals: The food we eat are chemicals, the nutrients plants need are chemicals.  All chemicals are not poisonous to all forms of life.  No matter if synthetic or nature-made, chemicals are reduced to their molecular makeup and are neither 'good' nor 'bad'. There are GREAT 'products' out there, not many!  We need to know/understand chemistry so we can lobby to get rid of or never use stuff on our lawns/gardens that IS truly contraindicated! I totally understand what you are meaning!!

Comment: I'm not a bag of toxic chemicals? Everyone who is, please raise your hand. You want a nice green lawn, than plant species that work in your soil & environment. If you can't or won't do that, than chuck some clover seed on your yard during the spring melt. Legumes (like clover) will re-insert all the nitrogen your grass needs, & it's not an ugly weed, plus the bees love it. We need to remember, we're not the only ones pulling bags of "toxic" fertilizers off the pallets at the store & dumping them into our ground water? Think of the MILLIONS upon MILLIONS of people doing so? Then, think again!

Comment: Oh for goodness sakes.  Chemicals are chemicals....period.  Toxic only means that the chemistry is wrong for whatever a human is trying to do.  Fertilizers ARE NOT TOXIC unless they are applied erroneously.  Fertilizer is as critical to plants in OUR stewardship as is water, light and drainage.

Comment: I dunno where this fertilizer is toxic stuff has come from but it is wrong and wronger!  If you want to worry about our drinking water...go find out where they are dumping our POOP!  You'll be horrified.  Fertilizer in no way JOSE is a problem.  Homeowners and use of pesticides ARE.

Comment: ...We humans, all animals, plants, rocks...everything are made of chemicals.  What is our periodic element table up to now?  103??  Like it or forget understanding life.  Clover is a great plant but not wanted within the monocrop of lawn grasses...my goodness, Wilberstone.  Let's have a chat in chat.  I am sigh, the queen of this beast cool season grass lawns.  We most certainly are on the same page and I am dying to help you understand.  Fertilizer is NOT toxic crap.  If one over applies fertilizer, they will experience all their plants dying.  Great feedback system....

Comment: @Wilberstone  Fertilizer, again is NOT toxic.  But to back up a bit, the making of phosphorous to put in the bags that plants have to have in their soil IS a problem.  These phosphorous plants have an extremely toxic by product called Fluoride.  There are lots of by products that get dumped under the label fluoride which is then sold to our city water systems to be put in our tap water.  I won't even use fluoride toothpaste and mouthwash!  One of these days we gardeners are going to have to learn to make our own balanced fertilizer.  After all, we need to know the formulations to be in...

Comment: ...CONTROL of the amounts/percentages of NPK and microchemicals (nutrients).  Just a little too much of one element, a lack of proper percentages, improper pH...can damage your little crop even kill it.  Fluoride is TOXIC. PTD or Possible Toxic Dose is 5mg per pound of an animal.  One tube of fluoride toothpaste will kill a child.  How the hell our country and a few others could con us into swallowing this truly very toxic...poison is amazing.  It does NOTHING for teeth!  Please rethink what is toxic and what we should be doing to get it out of our drinking water!!

Comment: Back to reel mowers...it is rare to find a reel mower that can be adjusted to 3".  I've seen them and they were custom fitted with adjustments and they were also motorized and they were sharpened every other mowing.  Rotary is the only way to go and you have to have at least one extra set of professionally sharpened blades.  I had a close relationship, always, with a great lawn equipment repair company.  And who just said this?  Those blades were changed out and resharpened for every other mowing commercially.  Dull blades rag the tips of grass and give a dusty look to the lawn.

Comment: Bagging the clippings is the only way to manage the lawn.  Balanced fertilizer up to 4 times a season...only twice for using the Organic New Age mix for lawns.  But to not fertilize the lawn, to depend on clippings for fertilizer is not at all productive, nor healthy.  Let's talk about an artificial crop!  A crop that needs artificial input by us humans!  It is a beast.  It is not natural.  Not a single garden built by man is natural.  Never will be...fertilizer is NOT TOXIC.  Just needs an educated human to use it correctly but just as important as water and sun.  Fluoride.  Please check out!